# How can i convert numpy array to pil image in memory?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have heatmap which is normalized 2d numpy array

When i plot it with matplotlib:

```
axes_img = plt.imshow(255 * normalized_heat_map, alpha=alpha, cmap=cmap)
plt.show()
```

[image]

However when i convert it to PIL image and then plot again

```
heatmap_image = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(axes_img.get_cmap()(axes_img.get_array()) * 255))
plt.imshow(np.asarray(heatmap_image))
plt.show()
```

[image]

How can I get image that is same to one from Matplotlib one **without saving to file**?

Comment: You describe your heatmap as a *"normalised Numpy array"*. What type does that mean to you? And what range of values?

Comment: Mean normalization, I use this formula `normalized_heat_map = (heat_map_resized - min_value) / (max_value - min_value)`

Comment: So they are floating point values between 0 and 1.0?

Comment: Yes thats correct

Comment: And what do you plan to do with the PIL Image?

Comment: I was thinking maybe there is some Gaussian Blur or other filter

Comment: Display image with heatmap that looks like it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `imshow` adjust the limits of the color scale to the minimum and maximum of the data you are plotting. If you keep this in mind, you realize you have to normalize the image array before converting it in an 8bit array. This can be done as follow:

```
scaled_img = (axes_img.get_array()-axes_img.get_clim()[0])/(axes_img.get_clim()[1]-axes_img.get_clim()[0])
heatmap_image = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(axes_img.get_cmap()(scaled_img) * 255))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Thats it !!